# Change android manifest permission based on android version

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using [BLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le) in an android library. In the manifest of this library i have specified the permissions required using the `<uses-permission ... />` tag:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

However, as of android-29 (Q), there is a requirement to use the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission instead.

I could simply update to `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` an be done with it, but then I require "too much" for devices running android-28 and below.

Is there a way to have my manifest include different permissions depending on OS version?

Comment: android-28 and below devices should still work with no problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved by setting up flavors and dimensions [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#flavor-dimensions)

```
 productFlavors {
    demo {
      // Assigns this product flavor to the "mode" flavor dimension.
      dimension "mode"
      ...
    }

    full {
      dimension "mode"
      ...
    }

    // Configurations in the "api" product flavors override those in "mode"
    // flavors and the defaultConfig block. Gradle determines the priority
    // between flavor dimensions based on the order in which they appear next
    // to the flavorDimensions property above--the first dimension has a higher
    // priority than the second, and so on.
    minApi24 {
      dimension "api"
      minSdkVersion 24
      // To ensure the target device receives the version of the app with
      // the highest compatible API level, assign version codes in increasing
      // value with API level. To learn more about assigning version codes to
      // support app updates and uploading to Google Play, read Multiple APK Support
      versionCode 30000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-minApi24"
      ...
    }
```

and manifest merging [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge)

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Can use Runtime permission on basis of android version